# Docker –host through SSH ProxyJump

Tags: docker

I have a setup where images are built on local and deployed to remote:

```
local ---> remote
```

But the remote should not be directly exposed to the internet:

```
local ---> ssh gateway ---> remote
```

The current script on local looks like this:

```sh
# Building
docker build $PATH

# Transferring images to remote

# Operations on remote
docker -H ssh://$USERNAME@$REMOTE_IP ps
```

How can I use `docker -H` with an SSH ProxyJump through the gateway?

I need to run docker locally and on the remote from local.

I cannot add any port binding on the gateway for SSH tunnelling, but I can do anything on local.

Comment: Why can't you `ssh $USERNAME@$REMOTE_IP docker ps`?  Trying to enable other paths to reach the Docker socket has massive security implications – anyone who can reach the socket has unrestricted root access over the host.

Comment: @DavidMaze I run `docker -H ssh://$username@$REMOTE_IP stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml name`, with this syntax the yml file from local is used. I do not know how not to transfer the file with the command you suggest. But thanks, maybe I should use it anyway as at least I can tunnel the connection.